# Convert main to button click event

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to give this to button click event in Visual C# .  I don't know how to do it.
here is the code .

```
public static void Main(string[] args){
    UdpClient udpc = new UdpClient(args[0],2055);
    IPEndPoint ep = null;

    while(true) {
        Console.Write("Name: ");

        string name = Console.ReadLine();

        if(name == "") break;

        byte[] sdata = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(name);    
        udpc.Send(sdata,sdata.Length);
        byte[] rdata = udpc.Receive(ref ep);    
        string job = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rdata);

        Console.WriteLine(job);
    }
}
```

Comment: Seem button_click on console app?

Comment: What you mean by `get in Visual Studio`? You can do `Debug.WriteLine()` and observe this message in Output Window

Comment: i know this is a console app  i want to convet into windows app

Comment: You have to make your question more clear :)

Comment: i want to put this into button click event but i get error                    UdpClient udpc = new UdpClient(args[0], 2055);

Answer (score 0):

Open Visual Studio,

On the **File** menu, click **New**, and then click **Project**….

In the Project Types pane, select C#, then select Windows Forms Application in the Templates pane.

Type a name for the project, such as winformsapp. You can accept the default location, type in a location, or browse to a directory where you want to save the project.

The Windows Forms Designer opens, showing **Form1** of the project you created.

Open Tool Box Window, Normally in the sides of VS

If the Toolbox window is not visible, click **Toolbox** on the View menu.

Drag a **button** to the Tool Box

Double Click the Button to get in to `button1_Click`() event. Move this code to there. `Console.WriteLine()` Will not work there. You could use `MessageBox.Show()`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to open a windows form from console application, you have to include : (you should add reference to the dll first)

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

then create new form object

```
Form myForm = new Form();
```

to display it call :

```
myForm..ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 0):

first you need to create the button in tne design page. click the button ,it will automatically redirect you to "your page name".cs page in the onclick place as below.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
```

`}`

place the code in between the braces.

Comment: I want to put this code inside but  I have go t an error... with this line    UdpClient udpc = new UdpClient(args[0],2055);                                                      but i get error with  this    UdpClient udpc = new UdpClient(args[0], 2055);